# how to download a mulipart form-data rest API with nodeJS/Express/ Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this schema to post a mulipart form-data with document and the post and the upload of the file is working file in a rest API with nodeJS/Express/ Mongo

But I want to retrieve it with a get route with the file that have the url stored in my schema.

How can I do this?

```
{
"_id":"5e98af2e8812b711e0940aab",
"title":"re",
"userId":"5e989748fd24c22cd8038af8",
"description":"FDSQFDSQFDS",
"type":"Car",
"city":"City",
"price":"23454",
"imageUrl":"images\\5e989748fd24c22cd8038af8dsq1587063108465.jpg"
}

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
//The code I want to have
  } catch (err) {
  }
})
```

Thank you

Comment: I found this `tutorial` you can use `multer` to `upload` and `download` `multi-part data` https://grokonez.com/node-js/nodejs-express-upload-multipartfiles-images-multer-jquery-ajax-bootstrap

Comment: It's a good tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper multipart form-data parser like https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy

Comment: For the upload I used multer. Can’t I use it for the download?